# What is hot key for Gmail `filter message like this`?

Tags: gmail

What is the shortcut keyboard for `filter message like this` in Gmail?

[image: Menu dropdown]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As mentioned already, there is no *direct shortcut* for the "Filter messages like this" menu option.

However, providing you have Keyboard Shortcuts enabled in settings, you can

1. Hit `.` (period / full stop) to drop down the "More" menu
2. Then use the cursor keys to navigate *down* 5 times (or *up* 2 or 3 times depending on whether you are viewing a single email or a *conversation*) to the "Filter messages like these" menu option
3. Then hit `Enter`.

Comment: Great hack, still much better than using the cursor!

Comment:  With this I used BetterTouchTools to trigger a series of key presses `. + ⬇️ + ⬇️ + ⬇️ + ⬇️ + ⬇️ + ENTER`

Comment: you can simplify to `. + ⬆️ + ⬆️ + Enter` :)

Comment: @vdegenne But if you are viewing a _conversation_ (as opposed to a single email) then it's "up 3 times" since there is an additional "Forward all" menu option.

Answer (score 0):

There's no shortcut key for what you're using. Refer to the list of available [shortcuts](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6594?hl=en&ctx=mail)